# How do I build an Excel function to find duplicates in a column, based on other criteria in other columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Basically I'm trying to figure out if the Client column repeats, but based on the following criteria.

Dates have to be different
Product is the same
Ticker is the same
Clients are obviously the same as well

| Dates | Product | Ticker | CLient | Yes? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13-June | Computer | XYZ | Greg | Y |
| 14-June | Computer | XYZ | Greg | Y |
| 14-June | Computer | XYZ | Sally |  |
| 15-June | Computer | ABC | Sally | Y |
| 16-June | Rocket | ABC | Sally |  |
| 17-June | Computer | ABC | Sally | Y |

Ideally, the Yes? column should contain my formula. I think I'm halfway there using counties,but I keep running into problems with the product bit.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What have you tried? I'd probably start with a `COUNTIFS`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the newest version of Excel, you can use `FILTER`.

For example:

```
=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(
FILTER($I$1:$L$6, $J$1:$J$6&$K$1:$K$6&$L$1:$L$6=J1&K1&L1)))>COUNTA(I1:L1),
"Y","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you will not use the "Y" result elsewhere in your file, I mean, if your aim is just to spot the duplicate values; just concat the fields Product, Ticker and Client in another column and apply conditional formatting to highlight duplicate values.

[image]